Holographic principle with infinitely many degrees of freedom?
The holographic principle entails a limit to the number of degrees of freedom or possible states in a system (which would be givem by its surface rather than its volume, thus they would be "encoded" on its boundary).
However, if the boundary is situated at infinity, and thus has an infinite volume, shouldn't it have an infinite boundary (having infinitely many degrees of freedom)?
Also, isn't AdS/CFT compatible with infinitely many degrees of freedom as mentioned here

Yes, both sides of AdS/CFT have infinitely many degrees of freedom.

@ConnorBehan so it doesn't really have a bound in the number of possible states?

Right. A bound on the number of states only comes about when you pick a spatially bounded region and declare that you're not going to consider the infinite amount of stuff outside it.
